# Is there a way to sync my chats across sessions while using prosody?

Tags: chat, xmpp, jabber

I am trying to setup my own prosody severer. I am using two clients (Pidgen/WinX and Xabber/Android). I am noticing that messages that I send to a contact appear only in that session. While replies from my contact appear on all sessions.

Is there a way around this? Is this a server issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that this feature is dependent on both the server and the client. The server and the client need to implement [XEP-0280](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0280.html) protocol ("Message Carbons").

- Pidgen does not support this feature.
- The Xabber Beta android app supports it.
- [Gajim](https://gajim.org/) supports this extension.
- On the server side, we had to include [mod_carbons](https://modules.prosody.im/mod_carbons.html).

Answer (score 0):

As you already wrote yourself, there's XEP-0280 (Message Carbons), but you would might want to have Message Archive Management (XEP-0313) as well, which is mod_mam for Prosody.